# Haskell: change all indices from a list to some value

Tags: haskell

If I am given a list of objects and another list for some indices from this list, is there an easy way to change every object in this list with an index from the list of indices to a different value?

E.g. I am hoping there exists some function f such that

```
f 0 [4,2,5] [6,5,8,4,3,6,2,7]
```

would output

```
[6,5,0,4,0,0,2,7]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no attempt or prior effort.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a beautiful version that uses `lens`:

```
import Control.Lens

f :: a -> [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
f x is = elements (`elem` is) .~ x
```

Here is an efficient version that doesn't have any dependencies other than `base`. Basically, we start by sorting (and removing duplicates from the) indices list. That way, we don't need to scan the whole list for every replacement.

```
import Data.List

f :: a -> [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
f x is xs = snd $ mapAccumR go is' (zip xs [1..])
   where
     is' = map head . group . sort $ is
     go [] (y,_) = ([],y)
     go (i:is) (y,j) = if i == j then (is,x) else (i:is,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a helper function to replace a single value and then use it to fold over your list.

```
replaceAll :: a -> [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
replaceAll repVal indices values = foldl (replaceValue repVal) values indices
                            where replaceValue val vals index = (take index vals) ++ [val] ++ (drop (index + 1) vals)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the indices first. Then you can traverse the two lists in tandem.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Prelude (Eq, Enum, Num, Ord, snd, (==), (<$>))
import Data.List (head, group, sort, zip)

f :: forall a. (Eq a, Enum a, Num a, Ord a) => a -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
f replacement indices values =
    go (head <$> group (sort indices)) (zip [0..] values)
  where
    go :: [a] -> [(a, a)] -> [a]
    go []     vs                     = snd <$> vs
    go _      []                     = []
    go (i:is) ((i', v):vs) | i == i' = replacement : go is vs
    go is     (v:vs)                 = snd v       : go is vs
```

The sorting incurs an extra *log* factor on the length of the index list, but the rest is linear.