# Haskell: map a list of indices to a string

Tags: haskell, dictionary, indexing

Hello: I have a sentence broken down in to separate words:

```
["this", "is", "a", "simple", "sentence"]
```

And I have a list of `indices = [0, 2, 4]`

I am trying to map the list of indices onto the sentence to return the words at the appropriate index, like this:
if we apply `indices [0, 2, 4]` to the sentence we get:

```
["this", "a", "sentence"]
```

Here's my code:

```
sentence !! [x | x <- indices]
```

this is the error message:

```
  <interactive>:215:7: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[Integer]’
• In the second argument of ‘(!!)’, namely ‘[x | x <- indices]’
  In the expression: tex !! [x | x <- indices]
  In an equation for ‘it’: it = sentence !! [x | x <- indices
```

I am especially interested in an answer that uses `(!!)` and/or list comprehensions.

Thank you

Comment: is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492989/haskell-change-all-indices-from-a-list-to-some-value/42493836#42493836 question useful to you - I think reading its answers carefully might guide you in the right direction; another hint - read up on `zip [1..]`

Comment: Have you read and thought about the error message? Rhetorical questions: what is the type of `indices`? What is the type of `(!!)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are almost there there is just one parenthesis wrong in your example
change:

```hs
sentence !! [x | x <- indices] -- (1)
```

to:

```
[sentence !! x | x <- indices] -- (2)
```

but why - well in the "list comprehension (1)" you try to apply the indexing operator `!!` to a list of indices, and the compiler tells you that it expects `Int` (i.e. an index) but you supply a list.

the latter (2) works because for each index - I fetch the element of that index from the list `sentence`.

*Side note*: as a beginner this is ok - but if your list is long and your indices are at the end - this takes some time, lists are not the data structure best suited for indexing - `Array`s, `IntMap`s, and `Seq` are way better suited

### Edit2:

If you like to get your brain going - think what could

```
zipWith (!!) (repeat sentence) indices
```

do

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for your explanatory notes.

Comment: If I may ask a follow-up question so that I understand fully what's going on: so when the compiler complains : Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[Integer]’ : actual type [Integer] here refers to my indices?

Comment: @omar Yes: "In the second argument of ‘(!!)’, namely ‘[x | x <- indices]’..." The second argument of `!!` expects an `Int` but you've given it a `[Integer]`

Answer (score 4):

This may seem a little weird, but `(sentence !!)` is actually a (partially applied) [function](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_application), with type `:: Int -> [Char]`. You can `map` it to your list of indexes to obtain the result you want:

```
> map (["this", "is", "a", "simple", "sentence"] !!) [0, 2, 4]
> ["this","a","sentence"]
```

Comment: sorry if I didn't upvote earlier. I am fairly new to SO. I assume to upvote I need to use the up arrow next to your answer, right?